# How to select columns based on their data types in pydatatable?

Tags: python, py-datatable

I'm creating a datatable as follows,

```
spotify_songs_dt = dt.fread('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2020/2020-01-21/spotify_songs.csv')
```

and its column types are,

```
spotify_songs_dt.stypes
```

Here I would like to take out only numeric fields of DT, and how can it be achieved in a datatable way?. In pandas dataframe we have a kind of function select_dtypes() for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a frame `DT`, then the most straightforward way to select columns of a specific type is to use the type itself in the `DT[:,j]` selector:

```py
DT[:, bool]          # all boolean columns
DT[:, int]           # all integer columns
DT[:, float]         # all floating columns
DT[:, str]           # string columns
DT[:, dt.int32]      # columns with stype int32
DT[:, dt.ltype.int]  # columns with ltype `int`, same as DT[:, int]
```

It is also possible to provide a list of types to select:

```py
DT[:, [int, float]]          # integer and floating columns
DT[:, [dt.int32, dt.int64]]  # int32 and int64 columns
```

Sometimes it may also be useful to delete the columns of the undesirable type instead of selecting the ones you need:

```py
del DT[:, str]
```

Comment: Now I got it and thanks for that answer. It’s a simple one, I missed it.